# Travel though all <img /> and replace .png with .svg

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I, in javascript or jquery, travel through each of the `<img />` tag in a page, check if it is a .png extension, replace the .png extension, if it is a .png extension, with .svg?

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you post that?

Comment: `$('img').each(function(i,e) { e.src = e.src.replace('.png', '.svg') })`

Comment: you could also use attributes ends with selector to only process png

Comment: @MartinSmith True, but it's probably just easier to find all image elements and not deal with **checking** at that point of the process. If you use the "ends with" selector, it's unnecessary checking where for the matched elements, you still have to target the ending ".png"

Comment: @Ian - But as you know all will match you can just use substring and be done with it. `$("img[src$='.png']").attr("src", function (idx, src) {return src.substring(0, src.length - 4) + ".svg";});`

Comment: @MartinSmith Absolutely, I would've argued less if you included that in your first comment :) I guess my point is that I'm not sure which is more critical (performance-wise) - calling a `replace` on **every** image (may or may not match and do anything), or filtering the images first and using `substring` (or `replace`) on those.

Comment: @Ian - The ends with is a CSS3 selector so I assume that in browsers that support this natively performance should be good but not a subject I'm very informed about. I may be entirely wrong in assuming this.

Comment: @MartinSmith Very true, I would hope that browsers that support it with `querySelectorAll` (what jQuery would use internally) could easily optimize it, but in the end, **something** has to **check** if the `src` ends with ".png" - either the jQuery selector (with your suggestion), or a `replace` (with the accepted answer's suggestion). I would say that your suggestion is great and worth it to make an answer, even if one has already been accepted. I'll gladly upvote it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The following is an edited version of my original answer thanks to the helpful comments.

```
$('img').each(function() {
  var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
  var new_src = img_src.replace(/\.png$/, '.svg');
  $(this).attr('src', new_src);
});
```

**Original**

I haven't tested this, but believe it should work.

```
$('img').each(function() {
  var img_src = $(this).attr('src');

  if(img_src.indexOf('.png')) {
    var new_src = img_src.replace('.png','.svg');
    $(this).attr('src', new_src);
  }
});
```

Comment: No need to check with indexOf - just replace - if theres no match, nothing will be replaced. And its probably safer to use: .replace(/\.png$/, ".svg")

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  After I posted this, I saw other answers that seemed to offer solutions more concise than mine.  I guess I've become overly-cautious with trying things like replace without making sure something is to be replaced!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: `img_src.indexOf('.png')` will pretty much always evaluate to truthy because `!!(-1)` is true

Comment: That's a good point.  I did this on the fly without looking up indexOf, and couldn't remember if it evaluated as -1 if not found or false.  Thank you for the correction and the information.

Comment: @JoshWa Like I said, you should use `var new_src = img_src.replace(/\.png$/, '.svg');`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of explicitly looping, you can take advantage of one of `.attr()`'s overloads:

```
$("img").attr("src", function (idx, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/\.png$/, ".svg");
});
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Comment: +1 You need to tell it what attribute though. `$("img").attr("src", function ...`

Comment: @MartinSmith Sheesh how did I forget that? Haha thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the sense of this question, anyway this is the code(it is untested, but it should work);

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i in imgs) {
    var img = imgs[i],
        ext = img.src.split('.').pop();
    if (ext.toLower() == 'png') {
        img.src = img.src.replace(/\.png$/, '.svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: This will incorrectly replace when a filename that ends with "png" alsos contain "png" not in the extension

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: You forget to initialize `toBeReplaced`

Comment: And this was my point with the other answer here - you don't need to **check** first, just execute the `replace`. If nothing matches, nothing will be replaced. So first, your loop should be `for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {`, and second, all that your loop needs to do is: `imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace(/\.png$/, toReplace);`

Comment: Isn't it better(or, at least, the same thing) to use a for...in loop in this case? As you surely know, it loops only through existing elements. So, using it with a list of HTMLElements should not give issues of any type. And I prefer to write code that is easily understandable to those who don't know how all functions work.
@Shikiryu edited, ty

Comment: @LightStyle Definitely not - `for in` loops are for iterating objects, normal `for` loops are for iterating arrays (or collections). `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, so you should use a normal `for` loop. Using `for in` on arrays has consequences...check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/U69By/1/ . I understand about writing code that is easily understandable, but it's unnecessary to do extra work when you can explain why only using `.replace()` is more than enough

Comment: I was referring to MSDN(it says you can use it with objects and arrays), and thank you, I didn't know about these "problems" with HTMLElement arrays. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/55wb2d34(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @LightStyle You're absolutely right, it's **valid** to use `for in` to iterate arrays, but it's not recommended. As MSDN even points out, it iterates over the array's values **and properties**. Especially with special implementations of arrays (like collections), extra things will be iterated. It gets messier when there are custom methods defined in the `prototype`, because they are enumerable. Of course, this can be fixed by using `Object.defineProperty` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), but it isn't supported in all browsers

Comment: @LightStyle Also, the point of arrays are that they preserve order, while objects do not. Using a normal `for` loop allows you to iterate in order, while `for in` does not. So it kinda makes sense to use the correct `for` loop based on purpose

Comment: As I said yesterday, I didn't know about these issues, thank you for your clarification, it is very useful to me. You're right, next time I'll use normal for loops instead of for...in! Since we're here, is it the same thing using a while(i--) (where i is the lenght of our HTMLElements collection)?